# Unable to connect to world in Minecraft Education Edition multiplayer

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-education-edition

It was working fine until the day before yesterday but yesterday none of my friends were able to connect. It just showed;

```
Unable to connect to world
```

Earlier there were 3 of us playing but now we were with 6. I have adequate RAM etc. Please tell me how to fix this.

PS: Can the school admin disable us from joining each other's worlds?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you check your join code in the pause menu if it doesn't work try pressing the refresh button. If that doesn't work I'll look more into it.

Comment: It remains on a whim. Somedays it works fine, others are not too good. Yesterday, 4 of my friends were able to connect and two weren't. After one of them left for a brief moment, he wasn't able to join again.